# Formatting numbers on Wordpress' Backend

Tags: php, wordpress, numbers, format

I have a custom field in wordpress' backend(for the admin to view and modify only) that only accepts numbers, however, my client wants this number to be formatted something like this:

he introduces lets say 980000, and after pressing tab, or clicking somewhere else, it takes this format: 980,000.00

I'm well aware of stuff like number_format(,2) and other functions that can format numbers, the problem comes when having this quantity sent, we would recieve the message: "Numbers only", because of the comas, is there any way to do this? I have no idea where to even start.

Thanks

Comment: What you need is simple change format before validation. If validation is done on server site, it should be easy to change it to normal number.

Comment: The problem is, it wont even let me send the information to format because I can only introduce numbers

Comment: How about just formatting the number where it is displayed? The column in the DB could be formatted as a `num` and would strip any non-numeric values even if you bypass validation.